# Is it possible to make wordpress LMS

Tags: customization

How do I change the "submitted on date" of a comment to an earlier date? I want to change the date that is displayed to the readers. As far as I know, I can change the date of the post by clicking the "quick edit" option. Is there something similar I can do with comments?

Comment: What's the LMS connection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but not through "Quick edit". You will need to "Edit" the comment (there is an "Edit" option under the comment text").

Then, in the upper right corner, you will see the date that the comment was entered. There is an "Edit" link under that date that lets you modify the date.